# Csharp : Load Checked Item List based on the Value in Combo Box

Tags: c#, sql, csharpcodeprovider

I am unable to get the expected results in the below code.

I am trying to select one item from the combo box and I need to get the corresponding values for the the selected item in the Checked List Box.
Example is the Manager and Reportees, So if I select one Manager I should see only the list of those employee who are reporting to the Manager that is selected.

[image]

My checked List box shows Empty.

My code below which I am raising on the Manager - Selected Item Change Event:

```
private void Cbreporting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql1 = "Select distinct empname from tbl_emp_details where isdeleted <>1 and [reporting manager]='@lm'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lm", Cbreporting.SelectedIndex);

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
            datareader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(datareader[0]);
            }

            con.Close();
            datareader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Checked list box is not showing the correspondant items.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing 2 command objects `com` and `cmd1` and your SqlParameter '@lm' is assigned to `com`. Bur your 'ExecuteReader' uses the `cmd1` object. Modify your code like below.

```
con.Open();
string sql1 = "Select distinct empname from tbl_emp_details where isdeleted <>1 and [reporting manager]='@lm'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lm", Cbreporting.SelectedIndex);

datareader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (datareader.Read())
{
     checkedListBox1.Items.Add(datareader[0]);
}

con.Close();
datareader.Close();
```